Recyclerview is being visible when click on a blank space of current fragment
In my main activity, I have a RecyclerView. Let's say I click on an item called "Back to 80s," which opens a corresponding fragment (occupying the full window). However, there's an issue: when I click on any blank space within the fragment, the RecyclerView briefly becomes visible. Additionally, if I click on a blank space where an item exists in the RecyclerView behind the current fragment, that specific fragment loads directly.
Expected Behavior:

Return from the current fragment.
RecyclerView becomes visible.
Click on a new item to open the respective fragment.

Actual Behavior:
After pressing blank space on the current fragment, the RecyclerView momentarily appears, and then the fragment corresponding to the touched item loads.
This issue occurs in every fragment, not just the "Back to 80s" fragment.
Current Behavior
Fragment
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".Buttons.backto80s_btn">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addtofavlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/favorite" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Add to Favorite"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sucess_backto80s"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sucessScreen_backto80s"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:background="#216f45"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
                android:text="Blast from the Past"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
                android:text="80s Unlocked — iconic tunes, bold fashion, and classic video games. Rediscover the decade that made history cool."
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/continueBtn_backto80s"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#cccccc"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
                android:text="Continue"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#505050"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutProgress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/backto80sClick"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#858386">
            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/calibriregular"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Bringing back neon lighting....."/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressbar_backto80s"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar" />



        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>




    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/backto80sGifSucess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sucess_backto80s"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addtofavlayout"
        android:src="@drawable/backto80sgifsucess"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backto80sClick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/backto80s" />


</RelativeLayout>

public class backto80s_btn extends Fragment {
    ImageView backto80sBtn;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    boolean isPressed = false;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    RelativeLayout layoutProgress, layoutSucess_backto80s;
    AppCompatButton continueBtn;

    MediaPlayer mp_success, mp;
    private GifImageView backto80sGifSucess;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_backto80s_btn, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = requireActivity().getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
        }
        backto80sGifSucess = view.findViewById(R.id.backto80sGifSucess);
        backto80sGifSucess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        backto80sBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.backto80sClick);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_backto80s);
        layoutProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.layoutProgress);
        layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mouseclick);
        // Move MediaPlayer initialization here
        mp_success = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(), R.raw.sucess);

        continueBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.continueBtn_backto80s);
        layoutSucess_backto80s = view.findViewById(R.id.sucess_backto80s);
        layoutSucess_backto80s.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        backto80sBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.mouseclick);
                mp_success = MediaPlayer.create(requireContext(), R.raw.sucess);
                backto80sBtn.setEnabled(false);
// Toggle between pressed and unpressed images
                isPressed = !isPressed;

                mp.start();

                if (isPressed) {
                    backto80sBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.backto80spressed);
                    // Delayed switch back to unpressed image after 500 milliseconds
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            backto80sBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.backto80s);
                            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            sucess(1);
                            progressBar.setMax(100);


                        }
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    backto80sBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.backto80s);
                }
            }
        });
        continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out,android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new backto80s_btn());

                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                transaction.commit();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void sucess(final float progress) {

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                sucess(progress + 0.5f); // Increase progress smoothly

                if (progress == 100) {

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (mp_success != null) {
                                mp_success.start();
                            }
                            layoutProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            backto80sBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            layoutSucess_backto80s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            backto80sGifSucess.setImageResource(R.drawable.backto80sgifsucess);
                            backto80sGifSucess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        }
                    }, 100); // Delay the call to onProgressReached90

                }
            }
        }, 20); // Adjust the delay as needed for smoother animation


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).showToolbar();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).hideToolbar();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseMediaPlayers();
    }

    private void releaseMediaPlayers() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        if (mp_success!=null){
            mp_success.release();
            mp_success = null;
        }
    }



}

Main Activity
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    BtnRecyclerViewAdapter btnRecyclerViewAdapter;
    int[] arr = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.escratrace, R.drawable.delete, R.drawable.alttablife, R.drawable.givemespace,R.drawable.previewlife,R.drawable.pauselife,R.drawable.undo,R.drawable.gobacktochildhood,R.drawable.backto80s};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.appToolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
        }
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.btnRecyclerView);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        btnRecyclerViewAdapter = new BtnRecyclerViewAdapter(arr, getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(btnRecyclerViewAdapter);

    }
    public void showToolbar() {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

    public void hideToolbar() {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }




}


Expected behaviour since you have a fade animation transition. Remove it or use another transition

But what the transtion has to do with this, and im using the trainsition on fragment loading and unloading or on specific event
